# CakePHP of boolean not shows label, how to show?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

The SQL type of `myField` is boolean ('t' or 'f'). I need "MyLabel" but the code below not works, show only a checkbox (is ok), not the label.

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('myField', array('value'=>'t', 'label'=>'MyLabel') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo $this->Form->input('myField', array('type' => 'checkbox, 'value'=>'t', 'label'=>'MyLabel') );
```